# optimizing my inner loop (ARM, android ndk)

Tags: android, c++, c, optimization, android-ndk

I'm writing an image processing app on android, and I'm trying to speed it up using the NDK. I have the following for-loop:

```
int x, y, c, idx;
const int pitch3 = pitch * 3;
float adj, result;

...

// px, py, u, u_bar are all float arrays of size nx*ny*3
// theta, tau, denom are float constants
// idx >= pitch3  
for(y=1;y<ny;++y)
{
  for(x=1;x<nx;++x)
  {
    for(c=0;c<3;++c)
    {
      adj = -px[idx] - py[idx] + px[idx - 3] + py[idx - pitch3];
      result = ((u[idx] - tau * adj) + tau * f[idx]) * denom;
      u_bar[idx] = result + theta * (result - u[idx]);
      u[idx] = result;
      ++idx;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to speed up this loop?

I'm thinking that using fixed-point arithmetic wouldn't do much, except on really old android phone (which I'm not going to target). Would writing it in assembly give a big improvement?

EDIT: I know I could use SIMD/NEON instructions, but they are not so common I think ...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but your calculation doesn't seem to use any of the loop variables, y, x, or c.  So in that sense the calculation can be moved outside of the loop.

Comment: Are you building for armeabi or armeabi-v7a?  The former uses soft float, the latter uses hard float but limits you to devices with ARMv7 CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're accessing the array as a flat structure, the 3 levels of looping is only increasing the value used for idx.  You can loop for (idx = pitch3; idx < nx*ny*3; idx++).

Another option is to move to fixed-point math.  Do you really need more than 64 bits of dynamic range?